# generate a number of independent splits of dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, scikit-learn

when using sklearn [split function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html), is it possible to produce k independent splits, namely, k splits that have at least one element not in common? If not, is there any other library that can be used?

Comment: An example would make it more clear.

Comment: only one element not in common? Completely disjoint OK? Then look at Kyle's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `cross_validation` module.

For what you want, [KFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html) should do the trick.